# How to insert queries with null values in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to insert queries with null values in SQL Server 2008?

eg:

```
  INSERT INTO QREMOTES...Account 
  (Name, AccountType, ParentRefListID)
  VALUES
  ('Josh Account', 'Expense', NULL)
```

as I know null keyword is used.. but here it is not helpful its how me error

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "QREMOTES" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "QREMOTES" could not INSERT INTO table "[QREMOTES]...[Account]". Unknown provider error.

Comment: Have you tried with a non-NULL value? From the error message, I highly doubt this has something to do with the `NULL` - it seems to be a more general problem ..

Comment: check your database design , maybe u already apply not null to your column

Comment: Try your query on SSMS and see if it works?

Answer (score 3):

Try like that

```
INSERT INTO QREMOTES...Account 
(Name, AccountType)
VALUES
('Josh Account', 'Expense')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
INSERT INTO QREMOTES...Account 
  (Name, AccountType, ParentRefListID)
  VALUES
  ('Josh Account', 'Expense', '')
```

Comment: That's not NULL though

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
INSERT INTO QREMOTES...Account 
  (Name, AccountType, ParentRefListID)
  VALUES
  ('Josh Account', 'Expense', NULL)
```